# Did iOS 7.1 break 4S iBeacon support? Proximity is always CLProximityUnknown on 4S and RSSI is always zero. Please help, in the middle of beta testing

Tags: ios, core-location, ibeacon, ios7.1

After I updated my 4S to iOS 7.1 my wifi suddenly stopped working, which is okay since I like the challenge of optimizing my app's performance. However, I've also noticed that iBeacon ranging may not be working properly as **the "proximity" is always reported as CLProximityUnknown and the RSSI value is always zero**. Just to clarify, the UUID, major and minor are being read as expected. It's just the proximity functionality that appears to be misfiring.

Given that my wifi stopped working, perhaps my 4S's hardware is simply failing. That being said, has anyone else seen this issue?

This is important because my app ignores iBeacons whose proximity is unknown. I may just get rid of this check though. **Does anyone know if CLProximityUnknown mean the beacon is further away than CLProximityFar? Or does it simply just mean it wasn't able to determine the beacon's proximity?**

**UPDATE:**

It's my 4S (which is kind of a relief). Looks like updating to iOS 7.1 fried my chip. =(

Thanks for the help guys!

**UPDATE 2**

Putting my iPhone 4S in the refrigerator for 30 minutes actually did the trick. My wifi works now too (likely temporary though as it'll probably overheat again). x_x

Comment: wifi and bluetooth are managed by the same chip, you might have both gone bad. CLProximityUnknown usually means you are two far away to approximate how far you are from the beacon, but with an RSSI at 0 it should means you don't detect the beacon at all. I would recommend you to try to find an other 4S to test on it.

Comment: Thanks man, I think my chip is bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CoreLocation still works in 7.1 on the iPhone 4S.  See my detailed test results [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22365156/1461050), which were done on a 4S.  So this is most likely an issue with your test setup, either the phone, the beacon or a combination of both.

First, do a reboot to see if the problem still persists as @gokhan-karaca suggests.  Then try another iBeacon (what kind are you using now?), ideally an iOS-based one if you have a second device to test with.  It may be that a software filter on the RSSI is rejecting the value measured by the bluetooth chip for some reason.

Comment: I was using a 4S and a 5. I think it's my 4S though because I had two friends with 4S's try it out. What's your take on the difference between CLProximityFar and CLProximityUnknown in terms of distance? Basically my app wants to be able to detect beacons that are relevant in terms of distance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to restart the iPhone.

[ibeacon does not apear in iPhone 4S](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22713260/ibeacon-does-not-apear-in-iphone-4s)

> The solution ended up being simply rebooting the iPhone as discussed in the comments below.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Tried it, but I think my phone is fried. =(

Answer (score 0):

Today I read this.. I was really going crazy about that.
http://beekn.net/2014/05/beacon-bug-apple-loses-ibeacon-ranging-drives-developers-mad/